# doc, docx, pdf, csv xls, xlsx extensons not working in livewire laravel - This driver does not support creating temporary URLs

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i am facing strange issue. When i upload the image(jpg,jpeg,png) file using livewire its working fine but when i try to upload any other file type its giving me error this error  **This driver does not support creating temporary URLs**. Not sure is livewire doesnot support to upload **doc, docx, pdf, csv xls, xlsx** if yes its very strange?. Or i am doing something wrong in code. here is my below code:-

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="save">
    
    <input type="file" wire:model="documnet">
    @error('documnet') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
         <!-- Progress Bar -->
    <div x-show="isUploading">
        <progress max="100" x-bind:value="progress"></progress>
    </div>
    <div wire:loading wire:target="save">Uploading...</div>
    <button type="submit">Save documnet</button>
</form>
```

In this user input any type of document (jpg, jpeg, png , doc, docx, pdf, csv xls, xlsx ). Here is my below component code

```
public function save(){
    $extension = $this->document->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // Filename to store
    $fileNameToStore = uniqid().'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    // Upload Image
    $path = $this->document->storeAs('public',$fileNameToStore);
}
```

[image]

Can anyone help  me what i am doing wrong or livewire not supports to upload these extensions?

Comment: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads#configuration

Answer (score 3):

publish the config file with,

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
```

Then add mime type of file you want to upload to preview_mimes under the temporary_upload_file in config file.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I added the `pdf` value to the `preview_mimes` array, and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supported file types for temporary file urls are set in:
config/livewire.php temporary_file_upload->preview_mimes array for support